# Subclass as argument in superclass's member function, C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, arguments

I'm new to OOP and I'm working on a C++ project. I isolated my problem to make answering easy but here's the real scenario:

I have a superclass member function, that modifies values inside the object that called it. The modification is based on a value coming from another object of the same class. This object is given to the function as the only parameter. Such as:
 `void BaseClass::function(BaseClass x) {}`

However, I created a subclass. And if the parameter is a subclass type, I want to modify its unique attribute, too.
 `void BaseClass::function(DerivedClass x) {}`

The problem is that the subclass is obviously defined later in the code.

I don't want it as two separate methods, because the calculation algorithm is already written inside, and also the solution I search for doesn't require to change the code at the places where the function is already in use. Besides, every other possibility that comes to mind (e.g. using `typeid()`) looks silly.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>   

class Base   
{   
protected:   
    //common attribute   
    const std::string name;   
public:   
    //constructor for common attribute   
    Base(const std::string nameString) : name(nameString) {}   
    //getter   
    std::string getName() { return name; }   
    //superclass as parameter   
    void test1(Base &example) { std::cout << example.getName(); }   
    //subclass as parameter (I'd want the line below to work)   
    //void test2(Derived &example) { std::cout << example.getNumber(); }   
};   
   
class Derived : private Base   
{   
protected:   
    //unique attribute   
    const std::string number;   
public:   
    //constructor   
    Derived(const std::string nameString, const std::string numberString) : Base(nameString),  
  number(numberString) {}
    //getter for unique attribute   
    std::string getNumber() { return number; }    
};    
    
int main ()    
{    
    Base object = Base("whatever");   
    Base baseParameter = Base("base");    
    Derived derivedParameter = Derived("derived", "12");    
    object.test1(baseParameter);    
    //object.test2(derivedParameter);    
    return 0;    
}
```

What is the standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `test2` a template, and ensure that it's only used with types derived from `Base`:

```
template<typename Derived>
void test2(Derived &example) 
{ 
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>);
  std::cout << example.getNumber(); 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Ed4rY).